# How can I create a Spatial Index on an Indexed View?

Tags: sql-server-2008, view, indexing, spatial, indexed-view

I have a view which already has `SchemaBinding` applied AND it has a `UNIQUE CLUSTERED` index.

Now, I'm trying to add a second index, which is a SPATIAL index ... and I get the following error message:-

[image]

And here's the a picture of the schema:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FFS - [I found my answer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb964740.aspx).

> > Spatial Indexes cannot be specified on indexed views.

The error message is incorrect / misleading.

*Cheers & Heads up to a [previous SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/976508/sql-server-adding-an-xml-index-to-a-calculated-column-on-a-view/976556#976556) which is very similar.*

Epic Fail again.

[image]

[image]