# Trying to see how I can improve the performance of this Sql query

Tags: performance, sql-server-2008

I've got a SQL query which is trying to find all the Neighbourhoods in some Counties.

When I use SQL Sentry Plan Explorer to visualize the query (IMO, a bit better than the tools provided with MS SSMS) it highlights a really slow performing part :-

Full Plan

[image]

Zoomed in ....

[image]

Details

[image]

SQL script:

```
 -- Update which Neighbourhoods are in these Counties.
INSERT INTO @NeighbourhoodCounties (NeighbourhoodId, CountyId)
 SELECT SubQuery.NeighbourhoodId, SubQuery.CountyId
 FROM (
  SELECT e.LocationId AS NeighbourhoodId, b.LocationId AS CountyId, 
      c.OriginalBoundary.STArea() AS CountyArea,
      c.OriginalBoundary.STIntersection(d.OriginalBoundary).STArea() AS IntersectionArea
  FROM @CountyIds a
   INNER JOIN [dbo].[Counties] b ON a.Id = b.LocationId
   INNER JOIN [dbo].[GeographyBoundaries] c ON b.LocationId = c.LocationId
   INNER JOIN [dbo].[GeographyBoundaries] d ON c.OriginalBoundary.STIntersects(d.OriginalBoundary) = 1
   INNER JOIN [dbo].[Neighbourhoods] e ON d.LocationId = e.LocationId
   ) SubQuery
    WHERE (SubQuery.IntersectionArea / SubQuery.CountyArea) * 100 > 5 -- a Neighbourhood has to be 5% or more to be considered 'Inside'
```

Can anyone help interpret this query? What do all these numbers mean? How can I use these numbers to help diagnose and improve my query?

[I tried to make an indexed view on the spatial table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5798487/how-can-i-create-a-spatial-index-on-an-indexed-view) but that failed miserably.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Is it slow or don't you like the 64.5% ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be normal. You have no thick bars anywhere with mostly seeks.

However, I do see that you have a function on a column in a JOIN

```
ON c.OriginalBoundary.STIntersects(d.OriginalBoundary) = 1
```

This won't help. And a computed column won't help either

And you also have a calculation on columns too in a WHERE = non-sargable

```
(SubQuery.IntersectionArea / SubQuery.CountyArea) * 100
```

On the face of it, the 64.5% seek is probably a consequence of these JOINs and the optimiser working around them

Comment: Yeah - I was afraid of this :( just kills me. this spatial stuff should be so much faster!